# How to display XML data as a table using CSS?

Tags: css, xml

I have the below code. I want to link the XML code to a style sheet, and display the data in a table. I have linked to the style sheet but how do I display the XML data in a table?

```
<!DOCTYPE products SYSTEM "support.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css"?>

<products>
  <product>Widows XP</product>
  <product>Windows Vista</product>
  <product>Windows 7</product>
  <product>Windows Server 2003</product>
  <product>Windows Server 2008</product>
  <product>Debian Linux</product>
  <product>RedHat Linux</product>
  <product>VMware Virtulization</product>
  <product>Microsoft Hyper-V</product>
</products>
```

Answer (score 6):

To display the given data in a table, use

```
products { display: table; }
product { display: table-cell; }
```

This displays the data as a one-row table. To add borders around cells, for example, add

```
product { border: solid 1px; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One other question how would I add a title to the table and display them in a row so that each products is listed one after the other IE the table would dispaly the title OS followed by Windows XP Windows Vista Windows 7

and so on.

Comment: If you need to add content, XSL might be a better tool, but for a simple static text, you can use generated content, e.g.
`products:before { display: table-cell; content: "OS"; font-weight: bold; border: solid 1px;}`